# segmented control: titleForSegmentAtIndex returns null every time

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a segmented control (Added via story board) and have set two segments (set in story board). When it is clicked it fires my 'segmentedIndexChanged:' method, but in that method i can't get the values (it always returns null) for either .selectedSegmentedIndex or titleForSegmentedAtIndex

```
-(IBAction) segmentedIndexChanged {

    NSLog(@"index, text value: %@ , %@", self.mySegControl.selectedSegmentIndex, [mySegControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:mySegControl.selectedSegmentIndex]

 );
    switch (self.mySegControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:

            NSLog(@"segmented 1 selected");
            break;
        case 1:
            NSLog(@"segmented 2  selected");

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the outlet is connected to the control? You can check by printing out `NSLog(@"%@", self.mySegControl)`

Also, usually, IBActions should have the form of `- (IBAction)action:(id)sender`, that way you would be able to access the sender (in this case the segmented control) without having an outlet to it as well.